# facebook api: how to get the photos uploaded by a userid

Tags: facebook-graph-api

There is facebook user url `https://www.facebook.com/adikks`

If i am loged in facebook. i can view the posts and images which are public

His userid (from `http://findmyfbid.com`) = `100000041026824`

Now i want to view the pics uploaded by the user which can be viewed by plublic using facebook api. I tried

`https://graph.facebook.com/100000041026824/photos?type=uploaded&fields=name,source&limit=50&access_token=XXXXXX`

also i tried

`https://graph.facebook.com/100000041026824/photos?type=uploaded&access_token=XXXXXX`

both gives

```
{
   "data": [

   ]
}
```

I tried this even in the graph api explorer:

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/100000041026824/photos?type=uploaded

It shows the same

```
{
   "data": [

   ]
}
```

In contrary I treid for a page:

the link = "https://www.facebook.com/HailHimalayas",
the id = 381200698651805

Now i want to view the pics uploaded in the page and viewed by public

I tried

https://graph.facebook.com/381200698651805/photos?type=uploaded&fields=name,source&limit=50&access_token=XXXXXX

```
It gives:

{
   "data": [
      {
         "name": "IN EVERY WALK INTO THE NATURE, ONE RECEIVES FAR MORE THEN HE SEEKS..!!\n\nHail Himalayas - Responsible Eco Tourism",
         "source": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfp1/t31.0-8/s720x720/10987450_723146627790542_4281069196911932678_o.jpg",
         "created_time": "2015-07-31T06:00:20+0000",
         "id": "723146627790542"
      },
      {
         "source": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xft1/t31.0-8/s720x720/11731578_722471167858088_6058874620639883829_o.jpg",
         "created_time": "2015-07-29T12:08:08+0000",
         "id": "722471167858088"
      },
      {
         "source": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfa1/t31.0-8/q88/s720x720/11741148_722471134524758_420698345443715826_o.jpg",
         "created_time": "2015-07-29T12:08:08+0000",
         "id": "722471134524758"
      },
.
.
.
.
.
```

Why the user pics are not shown while the page pics are shown using facebook api.